# Online algorithms to generate evenly distributed points in the unit square

Tags: algorithm, 2d, deterministic

I am looking for *online* algorithms to generate points that are reasonably uniformly distributed in the unit square.

- The number of points is not known in advance.
  For every *n*, the distribution of the first *n* points generated must be reasonably uniformly distributed.
- The coordinates are real (floating-point) numbers (between 0 and 1); so, not on a grid.
- The points need (must) not be random; in fact, I want a deterministic algorithm, with provable properties (not based on statistics).

Generating such points in the unit interval can be done by using the golden ratio *Phi*:

- Take as point *i* the number (*i* * *Phi*) mod 1.

How to do that in 2D?

If the number of points is known in advance to be *N*, then ((*Phi* * *i*) mod 1, *i*/*N*) works nicely. But that is not online.

For some *c*, the points ((*Phi* * *i*) mod 1, (*c* * *i*) mod 1) could work, but it is not clear which *c* is best.  Especially, for larger numbers of points, all *c* that I tried had clear deficiencies.

Comment: Have you tried ((Phi * 2i) mod 1, (Phi * (2i+1)) mod 1)?

Comment: @Dave This is actually quite bad: the points are constrained to two parallel diagonal lines. The two coordinates are not independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Martin Roberts ([The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Quasirandom
Sequences](http://extremelearning.com.au/unreasonable-effectiveness-of-quasirandom-sequences/),
2018) recommends multiples of (1/φ<sub>2</sub>,
1/φ<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) where φ<sub>2</sub> = cbrt((9 +
sqrt(69))/18) + cbrt((9 − sqrt(69))/18) is the [plastic
number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Another relevant reference is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence